Aplicación MAUI NET 8 se cierra en modo release activado el trimming cuando uso la clase Connectivity
Hola la app funcionaba bien en release y debug, solo agregue este código;
`IEnumerable<ConnectionProfile> profiles = Connectivity.Current.ConnectionProfiles;
bool redmovil = false;
if (profiles.Contains(ConnectionProfile.Cellular))
{
    redmovil= true;
}`

en debug la app corre pero en release no, deshabilite el trimming y funciona en release , pero subió 20 megas el tamaño de la apk , como puedo mantener el trimming para que no incremente el tamaño y que me funcione este código?
Gracias
